# EJB's not being injected in JAX-RS

Tags: jboss, jax-rs, cdi

I am using JBoss 6.2.0 EAP, I am trying to get my EJB's injected into my JAX-RS classes but I am getting a NullPointerEXception. It's definitely the CUstomerDAO class, because the error at line 29 is the printOut method being called on a null object. I added beans.xml to my WEB-INF. I am wondering if the servlet I added, or the web.xml configuration I added is giving me an error. I declared a datasource on the jboss server and its working fine. It's just the new stuff I added seems to throw the error. If anyone wants the project I can put it up.

Here are my files

Error stack trace

```
10:11:32,834 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar" (runtime-name: "mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar")
10:11:32,835 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /opt/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/deployments
10:11:33,508 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
10:11:33,536 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/tutorial]
10:11:33,769 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS018559: Deployed "mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar" (runtime-name : "mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar")
10:11:33,852 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
10:11:33,852 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
10:11:33,853 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) started in 6615ms - Started 160 of 220 services (58 services are passive or on-demand)
10:12:44,006 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (HttpManagementService-threads - 2) JBAS014900: Content added at location /opt/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/data/content/bc/c99f85aabe406819b2f1f6d5c660b3fcb0d231/content
10:12:51,778 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "webproject.war" (runtime-name: "webproject.war")
10:12:52,031 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016010: Warning while parsing vfs:/content/webproject.war/WEB-INF/beans.xml:6 SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = '              http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd' must have even number of URI's.
10:12:52,103 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for tutorial
10:12:52,239 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment webproject.war
10:12:52,267 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-2) JNDI bindings for session bean named WebProject in deployment unit deployment "webproject.war" are as follows:

    java:global/webproject/WebProject!com.example.ejbrest.WebProject
    java:app/webproject/WebProject!com.example.ejbrest.WebProject
    java:module/WebProject!com.example.ejbrest.WebProject
    java:global/webproject/WebProject
    java:app/webproject/WebProject
    java:module/WebProject

10:12:52,268 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-2) JNDI bindings for session bean named CustomerDAO in deployment unit deployment "webproject.war" are as follows:

    java:global/webproject/CustomerDAO!com.example.ejbrest.CustomerDAO
    java:app/webproject/CustomerDAO!com.example.ejbrest.CustomerDAO
    java:module/CustomerDAO!com.example.ejbrest.CustomerDAO
    java:global/webproject/CustomerDAO
    java:app/webproject/CustomerDAO
    java:module/CustomerDAO

10:12:52,270 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-2) JNDI bindings for session bean named CustomerWS in deployment unit deployment "webproject.war" are as follows:

    java:global/webproject/CustomerWS!com.example.ejbrest.CustomerWS
    java:app/webproject/CustomerWS!com.example.ejbrest.CustomerWS
    java:module/CustomerWS!com.example.ejbrest.CustomerWS
    java:global/webproject/CustomerWS
    java:app/webproject/CustomerWS
    java:module/CustomerWS

10:12:52,514 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: webproject.war
10:12:52,598 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000900 1.1.16 (redhat)
10:12:52,657 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment webproject.war
10:12:52,658 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'webproject.war#tutorial'
10:12:52,879 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final-redhat-2}
10:12:52,897 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3}
10:12:52,900 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
10:12:52,912 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
10:12:52,937 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: tutorial
    ...]
10:12:53,042 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
10:12:53,377 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
10:12:53,496 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
10:12:53,502 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
10:12:53,563 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.1.Final-redhat-1
10:12:54,400 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS018210: Register web context: /webproject
10:12:54,476 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) Found BeanManager at java:comp/BeanManager
10:12:55,057 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "webproject.war" (runtime-name : "webproject.war")
10:13:08,430 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class com.example.ejbrest.RestApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
10:13:08,441 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Adding singleton resource com.example.ejbrest.CustomerWS from Application javax.ws.rs.core.Application
10:13:08,649 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/webproject].[Resteasy]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet Resteasy threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:365) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:233) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:557) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]


Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.ejbrest.CustomerWS.getCustomer(CustomerWS.java:29) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 21 more
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <display-name>RestEasy sample Web Application</display-name>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.example.ejbrest.RestApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!--  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>-->
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/customers/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>



  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.ejbrest.ControllerServlet</servlet-class>
    <!--  <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>-->
  </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <!--  <url-pattern>/tutorial/*</url-pattern>-->
    <url-pattern>/application/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 

</web-app>
```

beans.xml

```
<!-- Marker file indicating CDI should be enabled -->
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="

      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd">
</beans>
<!--  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd" 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee -->
```

persistence.xml
:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="tutorial">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/tutorial</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Java classes:

```
package com.example.ejbrest;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.html.View;

@Path("/customers")
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class CustomerWS {


    @EJB
    private CustomerDAO customersDao;

    @GET
    @Path("/first/{id}")
    public Customer getCustomer(@PathParam("id") int id) {

        customersDao.printOut();

        return customersDao.getCustomer(id);
    }


    @GET
    @Path("/second/{id}")
    public View getCustomer() {
        System.out.println("Got in here! ! ! ");
        View v = new View("/application");
        //v.render(arg0, arg1);
        //System.out.println("path " + v.getPath());
        return v;
    }

    @POST
    public void addCustomers(List<Customer> customers) {
        customersDao.addCustomers(customers);
    }


}
```

CustomerDAO:

```
package com.example.ejbrest;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class CustomerDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Customer getCustomer(int id) {
        return em.find(Customer.class, id);
    }

    public void printOut(){
        System.out.println("AGGGGGH!");
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void addCustomers(List<Customer> customers) {
        for (Customer customer : customers) {
            em.persist(customer);
        }
    }

}
```

CustomerWS

```
package com.example.ejbrest;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.html.View;

@Path("/customers")
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class CustomerWS {


    @EJB
    private CustomerDAO customersDao;

    @GET
    @Path("/first/{id}")
    public Customer getCustomer(@PathParam("id") int id) {

        customersDao.printOut();

        return customersDao.getCustomer(id);
    }


    @GET
    @Path("/second/{id}")
    public View getCustomer() {
        System.out.println("Got in here! ! ! ");
        View v = new View("/application");
        //v.render(arg0, arg1);
        //System.out.println("path " + v.getPath());
        return v;
    }

    @POST
    public void addCustomers(List<Customer> customers) {
        customersDao.addCustomers(customers);
    }


}
```

Directory Structure

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the contents of your `WEB-INF/lib` folder?

Answer (score 1):

First of all several notes for your code:

1. you don't need beans.xml file in the project because use don't use CDI annotations but only EJB3 annotations
2. @LocalBean annotation is not required, @Stateless is enough to define local bean, detailed explanation could be found in [EJB 3.1 @LocalBean vs no annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889563/ejb-3-1-localbean-vs-no-annotation)
3. definition of listener,servlet and servlet-mapping elements for resteasy in web.xml is not required, JBoss/RestEasy(JAX-RS implementation library) adds this definitions automatically for you. Empty web.xml with root web-app element is sufficient.

Now to your problem:
Attribute CustomerWS.customersDao is not injected by EJB container because CustomerWS is not deployed as EJB bean by container, but only as JAX-RS resource by RestEasy. It's known drawback of RestEasy 2.x used in JBoss EAP 6.x, that restfull resource could not become EJB bean out of the box: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.6.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_EJB_Integration.html

All you need to do is define special context parameter in web.xml with comma separated jndi names of EJB beans which are also restfull resources managed by RestEasy. So in your case, you need to insert into web.xml following snippet:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.jndi.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>java:module/CustomerWS</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And that's all. Now CustomerWS class will be handled as EJB bean with working injections.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues, some of them might be red herrings so I figure I'll list them all out.

Don't include all of this resteasy configuration in your `web.xml`.  It's probably confusing the app server if nothing else.  You should have a JAX-RS application that looks like this:

```
@ApplicationPath("/customers")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    // nothing needed ...
}
```

and that's all that's needed.  Remove the resteasy listener and servlet from your config.

You're using a CDI 1.1 `beans.xml`.  EAP 6.2 is CDI 1.0 compliant.  Either make the file empty or use a CDI 1.0 tag in your file.

Do you in fact have two different `CustomerWS` classes? or was that a copy and paste issue?