# How to pass entity manager injected in statelesbean to dao without setter method

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb, ejb-3.1

I am working on a project where I have separated EJB such that they only carry out the business logic but not performing the queries. Then I also have the DAOs that performs the queries. For me to use the DAOs, I inject the DAOs in the EJB and with a method annotated @PostConstruct, I set the EntityManager in the DAO with the EntityManager injected in the bean like bellow:

```
public class ClazzDao implements ClazzDaoI{

  private EntityManager em;

  public void setEm(EntityManager em){
     this.em = em;
  }

  public List<Entity> list(){
      return em.createQuery("FROM Entity e").getResultList();
  }

}
```

And the EJB

```
@Stateless    
public class ClazzBean implements ClazzBeanI{
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  @Inject
  private ClazzDaoI clazzDao;

  @PostConstruct
  private void init(){
    clazzDao.setEm(em);
  }

  public BigDecimal sendEmailToMembers(){

     List<Entity> members = clazzDao.list();
     //do some stuff with data like say send emails...

  }

}
```

Is there a way that I can make the DAOs use the entity manager injected in the EJB without setting it at the @PostConstruct of the EJB?

Comment: Why don't you inject the entity manager in the DAO directly, where it's needed, instead of injecting it in the services, where it shouldn't be used?

Comment: I want to use EntityManager injected in the bean and I dont want to use DAO as the JavaBean as well. And again if I inject it in the DAO using @PersistenceContext, entity manager becomes null on using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use inject capability only in **container managed beans**. You dao class is outside of container management no way to inject the EntityManager into this object. Put you class into container management (EJB/CDI) if you need injection capability. By the way avoid to use unnecessary interfaces  [use non interface view instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889563/ejb-3-1-localbean-vs-no-annotation).

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure Are you using JAVA EE 6 OR HIGHER, Make the ClazzDao as Managed Bean, means either @ApplicationScoped/@SessionScoped

@ApplicationScoped
public class ClazzDao implements ClazzDaoI

CDI can inject ClazzDao ManagedBean.