# Injecting EJB via interface in Wildfly application

Tags: java, ejb, cdi

I am using wildfly 10.1.0 and JavaEE 7

I've got this interface:

```
public interface TestEjb {
    String something();
}
```

and this Ejb class implementing it:

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class TestEjbImpl implements TestEjb {

    @Override
    public String something() {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

When I am injecting it to my @Path annotated jax-rs class using

```
@Inject
private TestEjb testEjb;
```

It gives an error saying "WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type TestEjb with qualifiers @Default"

But when I inject it like

```
@Inject
private TestEjbImpl testEjb;
```

it works fine.
And which is surprising both ways work with no problems in jboss-eap-6.4. But why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are mixing CDI injection with EJB injection. Rather use `@EJB` (instead of `@Inject`) when injecting your EJB.

`@LocalBean` has a no-interface view. So, you have an interface with no view annotation and a bean with a no-interface view annotation. The EJB Container understands it as a no interface view.

The best way will be to annotate the `TestEjb` interface with `@Local` view and remove the `@LocalBean` from the `TestEjbImpl` implementation in order for your solution to work.

*Interface*

```
@Local
public interface TestEjb {
    String something();
}
```

*EJB*

```
@Stateless
public class TestEjbImpl implements TestEjb {

    @Override
    public String something() {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

*Injection time*

```
@EJB
private TestEjb testEjb;
```

I hope this helps.

[Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889563/ejb-3-1-localbean-vs-no-annotation)...

Comment: Thanks! It helped. But I would like to study this question more. And why do you think it worked fine in JBoss 6.4 and didn't in Wildfly 10?

Comment: Wildlfly 10 is Java EE 7 compliant. I don't know what JBoss 6.4 means.

Comment: Yes, I did it. Thanks. What I meant by JBoss 6.4 is jboss-eap-6.4

Comment: The reason why it didn't work is because, if an interface  is not annotated with @Local nor the ejb bean itself, then ejb specification mandates a remote view by default. In this case, cdi container will not be able to "see" the implementation.