# "Unsatisfied dependencies" with UnsatisfiedResolutionException when trying to inject EJB into another component

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm trying to implement Java EE's managed executor `ManagedExecutorService` to submit callable tasks, where each task makes a call to an injected bean method.

I'm using the `Instance` class to make the container aware of the task object, but when `get()` is executed the following exception is thrown:

> Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException:
>   org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001334:
>   Unsatisfied dependencies for type MyTask with qualifiers @Default

I'm running this on WildFly 14.

The injected bean:

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("MyBean printed");
    }
}
```

The task:

```
@Stateless
public class MyTask implements Callable<String> {

    @Inject
    MyBean myBean;

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("MyTask called");
        myBean.print();
        return "Task called";

    }
}
```

The task invoker:

```
@Stateless
public class TestBean {

    @Inject
    Instance<MyTask> myTaskInstance;

    @Resource
    private ManagedExecutorService executor;

    public void test() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        List<Callable<String>> tasks = new ArrayList<>(); 
        MyTask task = myTaskInstance.get();  // <------- Exception is thrown here
        tasks.add(task);
        MyTask task2 = myTaskInstance.get();
        tasks.add(task2);

        List<Future<String>> taskResults = null;
        taskResults = executor.invokeAll(tasks);

        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>(); 

        for(Future<String> taskResult : taskResults) {
                results.add(taskResult.get());
        }

    }
}
```

Why is the exception thrown and how to fix this problem? Is there a library missing in the classpath?

Comment: Why does the task need to be an EJB?

Comment: It doesn't have to be an EJB as long as it can inject the other EJB (MyBean in the example).

Comment: It seems a bit like you're re-inventing message driven beans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that with **MyTask** as an EJB implementing **Callable**, you've removed the **MyTask** class itself from the "bean type" of this bean, which means it can't be injected into `@Inject MyTask xxx` "client", according to the rules in the [CDI 2.0 spec](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#session_bean_types):

> 18.2.2. Bean types of a session bean
>
> The unrestricted set of bean types for a session bean contains all local interfaces of the bean and their superinterfaces. If the session bean has a no-interface view, the unrestricted set of bean types contains the bean class and all superclasses. In addition, java.lang.Object is a bean type of every session bean.

That's why Weld doesn't find a valid **MyTask** bean to satisfy the injection into your **TestBean** client.

You can give the **MyTask** EJB a no-interface view by adding the `@LocalBean` annotation, e.g.:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyTask implements Callable<String> {
```

Or, you can remove the `implements Callable` and refactor like:

```
public class MyTask {

    @Inject
    MyBean myBean;

    MyCallable callable = new MyCallable();

    public Callable getCallable() {
        return callable;
    }

    private class MyCallable implements Callable<String> {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {

            System.out.println("MyTask called");
            myBean.print();
            return "Task called";
        }
    }
}    

public class TestBean {

    // ...

    MyTask task = myTaskInstance.get(); 
    tasks.add(task.getCallable())

    // ...
}
```

See [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tejb_dvnoview.html) for a quick reference on the no-interface view, as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889563/ejb-3-1-localbean-vs-no-annotation) post for more discussion.

Comment: how to return a Callable? Callable is an interface

Comment: Updated answer referencing spec.